# Force relocation with realloc

Tags: c, unit-testing, realloc

I'm currently writing a heavily data oriented library in C. The last few hours I hunted for a segfault that was caused by a dangling pointer due to memory relocation with realloc somewhere deep inside the library. As this bug only occured due to a memory leak in another part of the library, I'm wondering if there's a way to make this class of bugs more reproducible.

I had the idea, that maybe there's a way to force realloc to relocate the allocated memory on every call. I would like to do this while unit testing to catch such bugs early.

Is there such a LD_PRELOAD library (or similiar) that hooks malloc/realloc/... calls in a way that it'll early crash for dangling pointers?

The library is intended to be cross platform, but I guess memory errors are one of the few portable things in C.

Comment: You can search Stack Overflow for “interpose” for ways to do what you request, although other tools, such as valgrind, may be more useful or useful in different ways.

Comment: If you are using `gcc`, then look at the `--wrap` option (see [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html)).  This will let you define your own `wrap_realloc()`, which the linker will call when any code calls `realloc()`.

Comment: There is no way to force relocation, but you can define `realloc` as a custom function that allocates a new area then copy data. Enable this function only when debug compile is on to avoid overhead in production release.

Comment: How large is your library? On which OS? Is it multi-threaded? How big is the data, the tests...? Is it free software? What does it do exactly? Please **edit your question** to give more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (at least on Linux) to (sometimes) detect dangling pointers and memory leaks. You'll better compile with debug info (in practice, use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` for all warnings and debug info with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)).

You could also use the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). So use also the `-fsanitize=address` [instrumentation option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html). You might want to use other sanitizers, perhaps `-fsanitize=undefined` and/or `-fsanitize=leak` ...

At last, you could redefine your own `realloc` (above plain `malloc` & `free`), or more carefully have some `myrealloc` function which *always* reallocates and moves memory.

You could even improve your code to add some [sentinel values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) or some [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in (or just after) several data structures or types.

You might read more about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) techniques (e.g. with the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/)). They provide useful insights, concepts and terminology. And [Boehm's GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) could also be used as a memory debugger.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but I bet that [Electric Fence](https://elinux.org/Electric_Fence) will solve your problem.

It is a malloc debugger that works by marking the memory pages inmediately after and before the allocated space as non readable/writable. As soon as any instruction tries to access them, a segmentation fault occurs. Usually this happens very far away from the point where the problem makes itself visible.